# cURL not working but file_put_contents() do?

Tags: php, curl

I have a code in cURL that should copy an image from a URL to my server:

```
$curl = curl_init( $url );
$file = fopen( $imageURL , 'wb' );
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_FILE , $file );
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_HEADER , true );
curl_setopt( $curl , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , true );
curl_exec( $curl );
curl_close( $curl );
fclose( $file );
```

it doesn't work correctly but `file_put_contents()` does. Is there something wrong with my cURL code?

Comment: Are you sure you have curl installed in your environment? It isn't standard, check with phpinfo();

Comment: Are you sure you're using CURLOPT_FILE right? Are you supposed to pass a file resource, or a file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dont set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true**. This will **include the header** in the output. So your image file will contain *response header* + *image data*. Remove that line or set it `false`.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple solutions, cURL probably isn't the best.

```
$remote_img = 'http://www.somwhere.com/images/image.jpg';
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($remote_img);
$path = 'images/';
imagejpeg($img, $path);
```

Would work nicely, but if you are set on cURL, try this:

```
$ch = curl_init ($img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($fullpath)){
    unlink($fullpath);
}
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
fclose($fp);
```

That should work as well.

Best of luck!

Comment: using gd will modify the quality of image. Thats not original image

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im He didn't reference that it should be - it's a good function to run for security, since what he is grabbing could technically be a malicious script if a user inputs it.